# Como grabar audio con html5, MediaRecorder y eventos button onmousedown, onmouseup?

Tags: javascript, html5, promesas, audio

Espero que me puedan ayudar con mi problema.
Soy nuevo por aquí, pero tratare de ser conciso en mi problema.

La idea es grabar audio en cualquier dispositivo, con el micrófono, a través de html5. **El problema que tengo es que la grabación debe hacerse con un botón, haciendo clic sostenido en el mismo y cuando este se suelte termine la grabación**.
Estoy reutilizando este código de Internet, que hace gran parte de lo que quiero.
pero con la diferencia que la terminación de la grabación es controlada por un **setTimeout** al final de la promesa.
Como puedo finalizar la grabación, solo con soltar el botón de la grabación?

Mi html:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Audio Recording Test</h1>
    <p>Habla!</p>    
    <button class="" id="action" onclick="" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()">recording...</button>
</div>
```

Mi js:

```
function mouseDown() {
//evento listen
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => {
    // store streaming data chunks in array
        const chunks = [];
        // create media recorder instance to initialize recording
        const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        // function to be called when data is received
        recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
            // add stream data to chunks
            chunks.push(e.data);
            console.log(recorder.state)
            // if recorder is 'inactive' then recording has finished
            if (recorder.state == 'inactive') {
                // convert stream data chunks to a 'webm or mpeg-3' audio format as a blob
                const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/mpeg-3' });
                // convert blob to URL so it can be assigned to a audio src attribute
                createAudioElement(URL.createObjectURL(blob), recorder);
            }
        };// start recording with 1 second time between receiving 'ondataavailable' events
        recorder.start(1000);

        setTimeout(() => {
            // this will trigger one final 'ondataavailable' event and set recorder state to 'inactive'
            recorder.stop(1000);
        }, 10000);
    }).catch(console.error);
        console.log("Clic sostenido, habla...");
};
```

Si no es claro o es necesaria mas información, me cuentan.
Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Tendrás que hacer básicamente 4 cosas, primero dejar la variable recorder de forma global, porque necesitarás controlar su estados desde dos funciones distintas **mouseDown** y **mouseUp**, así:

```
let recorder = null;
```

Luego en la función **mouseDown** tienes que quitar la línea donde hace el settimeOut(), esta:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    // this will trigger one final 'ondataavailable' event and set recorder state to 'inactive'
    recorder.stop(1000);
}, 10000);
```

y dentro de la condición donde se valida el estado a 'inactive', al final asignas el valor null a la variable recorder, así:

```
if (recorder.state == 'inactive') {
    // Código de antes
    recorder = null;
}
```

finalmente te creas la función **mouseUp**, que se encarga de detener al recorder, así:

```
function mouseUp() {
    if (recorder !== null) {
        recorder.stop(1000);
    }
}
```

Todos los cambios juntos se verían así:

```js
let recorder = null;

function mouseDown() {
    //evento listen
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => {
        // store streaming data chunks in array
        const chunks = [];
        // create media recorder instance to initialize recording
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        // function to be called when data is received
        recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
            // add stream data to chunks
            chunks.push(e.data);
            console.log(recorder.state)
            // if recorder is 'inactive' then recording has finished
            if (recorder.state == 'inactive') {
                // convert stream data chunks to a 'webm or mpeg-3' audio format as a blob
                const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/mpeg-3' });
                // convert blob to URL so it can be assigned to a audio src attribute
                createAudioElement(URL.createObjectURL(blob), recorder);
                recorder = null;
            }
        };// start recording with 1 second time between receiving 'ondataavailable' events
        recorder.start(1000);
    }).catch(console.error);
    console.log("Clic sostenido, habla...");
};

function mouseUp() {
    if (recorder !== null) {
        recorder.stop(1000);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Audio Recording Test</h1>
    <p>Habla!</p>
    <button class="" id="action" onclick="" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()">recording...</button>
</div>
```

*Nota: Quise probar pero siempre en consola me saca error de seguridad, pero a nivel de lógica vendría a ser como explico en la respuesta.*